# Javascript - await triggering at wrong time

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

I'm very new to `async` and `await`, I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I have a function call `register` and within that function I register a user, and then send some data about them to the server to build a "user profile" so to speak.

Problem I'm having is that I also have a function called `login` and that is also async and redirects the user *as soon as* they are registered.. meaning the "user profile" data never gets sent.

Here is my `register` function:

```
async register(user: User) {
    try {
      const result = await this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
      await this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.updateProfile({
        displayName: user.displayName,
        photoURL: ""
      }).then(() => {
        let currentUser = result;
        let date = new Date().getTime();
        let userData = {
          email: currentUser.email,
          displayName: currentUser.displayName,
          uid: currentUser.uid,
          created: date,
        }
        this.database.list('users').set(userData.uid, userData).then(() => {
            return;
        }); //I want to continue after this line is called. 
    return; 
      }, function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      });
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

Is my `await` in the wrong location? I want the `login` function to get called once the data is `.set`...

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong.. I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: if `set` returns a Promise, add a return statement to that line. And also add `return`  to the line that starts with `this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.updateProfile`

Comment: you'd also need to `await this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.updateProfile`

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried that. It doesn't work..

Comment: @JaromandaX I updated my code above..

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari I updated my code above and it still doesn't work...

Comment: Why are you doing `await promise.then(nextthing)` instead of just `await promise; nextthing`?

Comment: you didn't `return this.database.list('users').set...` like the **first** comment said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of using [`async / await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) is that you don't have to deal with `then()` or `catch()`.

```
async function register(user: User) {
  try {
    const result = await this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);

    await this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.updateProfile({
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoURL: ""
    });

    let currentUser = result;
    let date = new Date().getTime();
    let userData = {
      email: currentUser.email,
      displayName: currentUser.displayName,
      uid: currentUser.uid,
      created: date,
    };

    await this.database.list('users').set(userData.uid, userData)

    // Do something after everything above is executed

    return; 
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

await lets you wait on a promise. One of the largest benefits of async-await is not having to use `then` syntax or any explicit promises. Not sure why you mix styles. It is extremely simple to 'do more stuff' after an await statement.

Here is some pseudocode. I took out the try catch because your entire function is in it, which makes it rather pointless. Also, if any promise rejects, it is translated into an exception. If an exception occurs within a promise, it is translated into a rejection which is then translated into an exception. Other exceptions outside of promises are plain old exceptions.

I took the liberty of adding the TypeScript tag to your question because you posted TypeScript syntax. *TypeScript is not Javascript*.

```
async register(user: User) {
  const result = await createUser(...);
  await updateProfile(...);
  const userData = buildUserData(...);
  await setUserData(database, userData);
  console.log('more stuff after setUserData');
}
```